# 4inch launch image retina not working in iphone4 launch image

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios-simulator, retina-display

I used `Default-568h@2x.png` for iphone5 screen. But in xcode4.2 launch image working in iphone5 simulator fine. When i used this  launch image, it works fine in iphone5. But in iphone4  launch image is stretching. I used `autoresizingMask`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you placed Default@2x.png, Default.png and Default-568h@2x.png

Also make sure you placed same in xcode summary page.

[image]

Comment: In xcode4.2 having only two options for launch image..I have code for iphone4. When i installed xcode latest version only add Default-568h@2x.png this image ok or do any autoresize..

Comment: Default@2x.png: 640x960, Default.png: 320x480 and Default-568h@2x.png : 640x1136

Comment: Is any autoresize need or any additional code need? because i used frame height,width is 320,480 in my coding...Also set button,text size is for iphone4 width,height size

Comment: for defalut image, just use that size..no need to do any coding...just add default image with right size.

Comment: I setframe for init method in all views. Then how can i comfortable with?

Comment: that is different question..please ask in new question...some expert may help.